# animating an SVG <path> element in a <g> tag

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm attempting to use :hover in CSS to get a slice of a circle to rotate.

The CSS I'm attempting to use will cause the slice to rotate as I would expect. However, when I add the :hover selector, it doesn't rotate.

**My HTML and CSS  is below:**

```css
transform-origin: 190px 50px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: transform 10s;
}

#box:hover {
  fill-opacity: 0%;
  stroke: black;
}

#circle:hover {
  transform-origin: 10% 10%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: transform 2s;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="divThree">
    <svg id="box" version="1.1" width="500" height="300" viewBox="0 0 500 300" xmlns="htp://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g class="slice">
        <path d="M 50 50 H 190 V 190 C 190 190, 58.99 189.99, 50 50"></path>
      </g>
      <circle id="circle" cx="190" cy="50" r="140" fill-opacity="0.0" stroke="red "fill="black"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

My [codepen](https://codepen.io/rynsp8/pen/ZEGJrbV?editors=1100) is here.

Comment: How exactly you want this slice to move? Something like this?
https://codepen.io/emtei/pen/XWbzNRy

Comment: Yes, that was how I wanted it to move, however, I wanted it to move by hovering on the .slice, not #box.  So, using #box:hover .slice{} does select what I want to move, but when only if I hover on the box... I'd want something like #box .slice:hover, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS code is fine. You can do `#box .slice:hover`.

But you should look at your SVG: there is `<g class="slice">` before `<circle ...`. So `circle` overlaps your slice, in this case `slice` will never be hovered.

Simplest solution will be to just move `circle` before slice:

```
<svg id="box" version="1.1" width="500" height="300" viewBox="0 0 500 300" xmlns="htp://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle id="circle" cx="190" cy="50" r="140" fill-opacity="0.0" stroke="red "fill="black"/>
    <g class="slice">
        <path d="M 50 50 H 190 V 190 C 190 190, 58.99 189.99, 50 50"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

or you can disable [pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) for `circle`:

```
#box circle {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Working solution: https://codepen.io/emtei/pen/PoqObRp?editors=1100